# Can we submit windows phone 8 app based on html?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I do not have Windows Phone tools SDK 8.0. Also, I don't want to create an app in XAML.

What I want to do is show one url page on windows phone 8 and **publish on marketplace account**.

My android code looks like this:

```
String uri = "http://websitename.nl/index.php?device_id=" + deviceId + "&nocache=" + Integer.toString(random);
myWebView.loadUrl( uri, noCacheHeaders);
```

Comment: What does this add to the user experience? Will it create a positive image for you as a developer or microsoft as a publisher? The answer is no, which is why it is not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

[App policies for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184841%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), §2.10:

> Your app and metadata must have distinct, substantial and legitimate
>   content and purpose.
>
> Your app must be fully functional when acquired from the Windows Phone
>   Store and **it must provide functionality other than launching a
>   webpage**.
>
> Your app must not be unreasonably priced in relation to the
>   functionality of the app.

Comment: I'm interested in how they define reasonable pricing!

Comment: @Gusdor I think it's vague on purpose. IMO, the idea is to be able to remove an application from the store in case the price is _just too high_ (see http://technologizer.com/2008/08/05/the-first-1000-iphone-application/ for example)

Comment: the skeptic in me believes Microsoft might use clauses like this to finger developers who step on their toes ;)

Comment: @Gusdor this I am Rich app surely qualified for reasonable pricing! :) http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=6090943b-3b1a-4c96-aba5-c924701862a6